# Убрать отправку на обработчик формы

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, post, form

Есть сайт, на котором две формы. Одна из них находится в index.php, вторая в portfolio.html.Обе формы работают через метод Пост. Есть скрипт и обработчик. Так вот, из первой формы все приходит и работает нормально. А со второй приходит нормально, но страницу перекидывает на обработчик (mail.php). Вторую форму я просто скопировал с первой и вставил в нужное место.

Форма где работает не правильно:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('.error').remove();

    var that = $(this);
    var valid = validate();

    if (!$.isEmptyObject(valid)) {
      $.each(valid, function(i, e) {
        addError(that, i, e);
      });
    } else {
      $('.error').remove();
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function() {
          $(".js-overlay-thank-you").fadeIn();
          $(this).find("input").val('');
          $("#form").trigger("reset");
        }
      });
    }
  });
});

$(".js-close-thank-you").click(function() { // по клику на крестик
  $(".js-overlay-thank-you").fadeOut();
});

$(document).mouseup(function(e) { // по клику вне попапа
  var popup = $(".popup");
  if (e.target != popup[0] && popup.has(e.target).length === 0) {
    $(".js-overlay-thank-you").fadeOut();
  }
});

function validate() {
  var errors = {};
  if ($('#form input[name = \'name\']').val() == '') {
    errors.name = 'Заполните поле имя';
  }
  if ($('#form input[name = \'email\']').val() == '') {
    errors.email = 'Заполните поле email';
  }
  if ($('#form input[name = \'phone\']').val() == '') {
    errors.phone = 'Заполните поле phone';
  }

  return errors;
};

function addError(form, input_name, error) {
  form.find('input[name = \'' + input_name + '\']').after('<p class="error">' + error + '</p>');
};
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="forma">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Мы сделаем все за вас.<br>Всего лишь заполните форму ниже.</h1>
    <div class="formets">
      <form class="form" method="post" action="mail.php" id="form">
        <div class="inputs">
          <input type="text" name="name" id="inpt" placeholder="Ваше имя" required>
          <input type="email" name="email" id="inpt" placeholder="Ваш E-mail" required>
          <input type="tel" name="phone" id="inpt" placeholder="Ваш телефон" required></div>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="buton" id="buton" value="Отправить">
      </form>
      <div class="overlay js-overlay-thank-you">
        <div class="popup js-thank-you">
          <div class="text-popup">Спасибо за заявку. Мы свяжемся с вами в ближайшее время!</div>
          <div class="close-popup js-close-thank-you"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Обработчик формы:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
        $title = 'Заявка с сайта BadyBack Design';
        $name = substr(htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['name'])), 0, 1000);
        $email =  substr(htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['email'])), 0, 1000); 
        $phone = substr(htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['phone'])), 0, 1000);
        $mess = '
        С сайта была отправлена заявка:
        Имя отправителя: '.$_POST['name'].'
        E-mail: '.$_POST['email'].'
        Телефон: '.$_POST['phone'].'
        ';
        // $to - кому отправляем 
        $to = 'me@gmail.com';
        // функция, которая отправляет наше письмо
        mail($to, $title, $mess, 'From:'.$email);  
}
?>
```

Помогите пожалуйста, где я допустил ошибку? И что нужно скинуть сюда еще?

Comment: потому что у вас указано отправлять mail.php – `action="mail.php"` и `url: "../mail.php",`. В чем проблема то?

Comment: @korytoff, html-документ находиться рядом с mail.php, а JS-файл находиться в папке ниже. Соответственно, нужно в скрипте выйти на папку выше, где и находится mail.php

Comment: @korytoff или я что-то не так делаю?)

Comment: JS выполняется на клиенте и там нет понятий как "папка". Напишите полный адрес. Проблема то в чем?

Comment: @korytoff Всмысле в чем? Я же говорю, отправляю форму, а меня перекидывает на страницу обработчика (mail.php) мне этого не нужно. Если убрать action, то на почту вообще ничего не приходит

Comment: отлично. Вот вы говорите "не нужно". Ну ок. А что нужно то?

Comment: @korytoff показать попап с благодарностью. 2 формы на сайте есть. У первой все работает так как надо, вторая - копия первой (абсолютно идентичная), на ней не работает нормально. ВОПРОС: КАК СДЕЛАТЬ ЧТОБ РАБОТАЛО?

Comment: На вопрос, как сделать – руками. Тут нет телепатов. Нужно понимать в чем проблема то. А у вас JS вообще подключен на странице?

Comment: @korytoff да, подключен

Comment: ну тогда смотрите в инспекторе браузера, что у вас за ошибка в JS коде

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно, потому что через ajax идет обращение к id="form", если Вы скопировали вторую форму из первой, то у Вас в html получилось два id="form". Такого быть не должно, поскольку браузер воспринимает только один уникальный id на странице, второй будет игнорировать. Попробуйте вторую форму обозначить id="form2" и внести изменения в ajax чтобы он перехватывал post запросы для обоих id.

Comment: Или назначить обеим формам одинаковый класс и выбирать по нему.